# Ploneboard manager role to non site manager user

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I use [Ploneboard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Ploneboard) inside my plone website. I created a group `Forum managers` for users that will manage my forum. I think there must be a custom role added to this group and the custom role will have custom forum permissions (Adding Forum, Adding Posts, etc.) added.

How can I give all permissions related to forum to this group members without giving them the global site manager role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general terms: if you go to the ZMI (`.../manage`), and there to the security tab, you will have the possibility of adding a user defined role, at the very bottom.

Once you've done that, you can

1. give permissions to that role, it will show up as another column in the security tab. (This is vague, since I don't have a PloneBoard here to tell you the exact rights you want to give to them, but it's customary that they'd start with "Ploneboard", [this](https://github.com/collective/Products.Ploneboard/blob/master/src/Products/Ploneboard/permissions.py) looks like the current list.)
2. give that role to users or groups of your site in the ordinary overview panel (`.../@@usergroup-groupprefs`): it appears as another role next to Contributor, Editor et al.

(Disclaimer: This approach might not reflect Plone current best practice. It also doesn't cover how to do it in code.)

Comment: Solved first part. I have now the new role with all ploneboard permissions added to it. I see here /manage_listLocalRoles i can add the new role to a user. If possible I want to add it to my group members at once, not for one user at a time. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: This was simple. :) In Users and groups I searched my group and checked role.

Comment: @GhitaB: Just updates the answer to point you at .../@@usergroup-groupprefs :)

Comment: Something is wrong and I think this is because of some bugs in Ploneboard. It seems given permissions are not working for a simple user that receive them.

Comment: @GhitaB: you may have to look at `portal_workflows` in the ZMI, because sometimes, permissions depend on the state of the objects as well. (Plain Plone example is where you can't edit a page once a Reviewer has published it for you, you need to retract it first.) Sorry for the wild goose chase, but you'll have seen pretty much every aspect of Plone's permission structure at the end.

Comment: I found I must go to existing forum (Ploneboard Message Board) in @@manage_access and to check all permissions related to ploneboard for forum manager role. It fixed my problem. But it is strange... I think this must happen automatically.